# SSIS Azure Blob upload task : Secure way to provide Storage Account key as Key URI in AzureStorageConnection

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-storage-account

I am using SSIS Azure Blob Upload task to upload the files from local directory to Azure Blob Storage container. In the **AzureStorageConnection I had to provide the Account key explicitly which I feel not secure**. Is there a way to establish the connection through KeyURI instead of Account key? I read some articles on Key-Vault implementation but to how to achieve it here.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to protect the Azure account key, Please consider using Shared Access Signatures (SAS). Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) for more information. Here is a snippet in the article:

> Using a shared access signature (SAS) is a powerful way to grant limited access to objects in your storage account to other clients, **without having to expose your account key**.

Comment: The poster's problem is that you cannot use an SAS in the SSIS Azure Blob Storage connection.

Comment: I agree with Brad.  It is unfortunate that [Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-2017) does not support the use of SAS keys, only account keys.